# Why roxygen2 doesn't show the web link

Tags: r, roxygen2

I was wondering why `roxygen2` doesn't show the following in my R documentation?

The **web link** is from ***Open Science Framework*** and is an `https`. Is there a quick fix here?

`#' @seealso This supplemetary document also explians what Partial Eta Square is: \url{https://mfr.osf.io/render?url=https://osf.io/7acye/?action=download%26mode=render}`

Comment: escape the percent sign